# Grouping of the bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, bubble-chart

This is the working fiddle of the bubble chart - [fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/pKhRxHxmuUBL2CHT1yXK?p=preview)

I want to perform grouping into 5 classes based on the "size" values in `flare.json` file given in the fiddle.Example -

100-5000   //all the size values between 100-5000 should be in this range

5000-10000

10000-15000

15000-20000

20000-25000

I have tried finding and displayed the maximum and minimum values in `console.log` but I am unable to understand how to perform grouping and display for bubble charts.

I would graciously appreciate if anyone can spare some time and provide me a help.

Comment: You want to do something like that : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530, but group by size ?

Comment: Yes Sir..this visualization is good and I want to group by size but I am unable to understand how to group them according to my given size conditions and display them.Please guide me Sir.Thank you.